# Add round corners to a jpeg file

Tags: php, rounding, background-color, imagick

I am trying to add round corners to a jpeg file, but the problem is that after adding round corners, I am getting a black background color. Somehow I am not able to change it to any other color (white, transparent, red). It just simply shows black background where the image has rounded corners.

The code that I am using is:

```
<?php

    $image = new Imagick('example.jpg');
    $image->setBackgroundColor("red");
    $image->setImageFormat("jpg");
    $image->roundCorners(575,575);
    $image->writeImage("rounded.jpg");
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    echo $image;

?>
```

I cannot use png as the jpeg files are huge, about 5 MB, so if I used png, the file size would go up to 26 MB, even though the png adds transparent round corners.

Also the IMagick version that i am using is:

```
ImageMagick 6.6.2-10 2010-06-29 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Also the output(image generated) will get printed so I don't know if css will work over here.

Sorry, I am trying to actually create a new jpeg file with rounded corners from an already existing jpeg file that doesn't have round corners this is actually a photograph taken from a camera, so there are multiple/too many colors so I can't use gif as well.

Also my site will only just generate the round corner image then afterwards it will get downloaded using a FTP program by the admin of the site and then using a system software will get printed, so in short my website will not be printing the image but rather just generate it

Comment: Actual file size should not really be an issue. If PNG works for you then use PNGS since you get transparency built in.

Comment: Problem is that if i use png then not only the file size increase but so does the execution time For Jpeg it is 5 Sec for PNG it is 80 Secs

Comment: Then what you need is more RAM! :)

Comment: Can you just test the above code in your pc because even the photoshop is taking too long to convert and save a jpeg file which is 5 mb in size to a png file. Also i have 3 gb RAM with me. The resolution of the file is 5200x3200

Comment: I don't have the same setup to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$input = 'example.jpg';
$size = getimagesize($input);
$background = new Imagick();
$background->newImage($size[0], $size[1], new ImagickPixel('red'));
$image = new Imagick($input);
$image->setImageFormat("png");
$image->roundCorners(575,575);
$image->compositeImage($background, imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTATOP, 0, 0);
$image->writeImage("rounded.jpg");
?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot i was finally able to change the black background in the jpg file

Answer (score 2):

I may get downvoted, but I say let css deal with the corners and take some load off of your server :)

[CSS rounded corners.](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/)

Comment: the output will get printed so i don't know if css will work over here

Comment: You're pulling an image from the file system, adding rounded corners and serving it up. What a waste of resources. <a href="example.jpeg" style="-webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;"> I just realized that there is no backtick key on my iPad in Jump remote desktop...ha

Comment: Ha, so now we have to read their minds when they ask specific questions with blocks of code attached? :)

Comment: my first comment should be <img src=  obviously, wont let me edit now.

Comment: @keyboardSmasher i have already said that i will be printing the image in the end, if that weren't the case then i would have simply used webkit solution, but i need to modify the image itself, you really don't need to read my mind just read the question more carefully also $echo is only for testing purpose

Comment: Use print stylesheet, it's with media="print" when you including you css on a page.

Comment: can you please tell me something more about it i have no idea about it, also my site will only just generate the round corner image then afterwards it will get downloaded using a FTP program by the admin and then using a system software will get printed

Comment: @Aditya - in that case this solution won't work.  You have the lines `header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); echo $image;` in your example, which makes it look like your image is served via HTTP to a webpage, where CSS can be applied.  If that's not the case, then CSS is not an option.

Comment: yes the header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); echo $image; is for only testing purpose i will remove it from the final draft

Answer (score 2):

JPG doesn't have a transparent color(s) (alpha channels) in its palette.

The output image must use either PNG or GIF (or another image format that supports alpha channels).

[setImageBackgroundColor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagebackgroundcolor.php) is another option if you want an opaque background.

---

*EDIT*

Your comment reminds me that you could try to use the command line; `shell_exec()` will run a command line argument from PHP.  The command in the ImageMagick API you'll need to start with is `convert example.jpg`, and then you can pass flags with the various parameters you want.

Since ImageMagick is already installed, it will work right away.  You may need to point your system `PATH` to the ImageMagick directory where all of the executables are.

There's plenty of questions and forums dedicated to rounded corners with this method so I'll leave that up to you.

Here's a helpful tip though - there is a silly confusion with the `convert` command, since Windows also has a `convert.exe` that is rarely used, but will confuse your command line, so make sure you're calling the right `convert`. ;)  To test if it's working, try `convert example.jpg example.gif` (which should convert your example to a gif).

To get output from your command line, finish all commands with `2>&1` which will pipe `cmd` [output back into PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-is-21).

Comment: transparent is not what i am aiming for i just need to change the black color that is getting displayed as the background

Comment: I tried "setImageBackgroundColor" even then it won't work
I also tried
$image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel("red"));
$image->setBackgroundColor("red");
$image->setImageBackgroundColor("red");

One at a time but none of them seems to work

Comment: i once read someone wrote that you need to add

-alpha off:- "adding this prevents the JPG to be created with a black background"

But it didn't say where exactly or how am i suppose to add it to my php script