# php imagick image rounded corners black background

Tags: php, imagick

```
        $image = new Imagick($destinationPath.'/'.$filename);
        $image->roundCorners(1575,1575);
```

I'am uploading different images, one image background is transparent when I make corners rounded, but the other image background is black, why is that? and from what is depending this behaviour?

I've tried to do this:

```
$img->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
```

but the background is still black, someone knows which method can handle this?

Comment: try this solution --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579272/php-imagick-add-round-corners-to-a-jpeg-file

Comment: possible duplicate of [php imagick rounded corners with transparent background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766178/php-imagick-rounded-corners-with-transparent-background)

Comment: Please don't make duplicate questions. Please edit your original question to be better if it gets downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

If the source image is a JPEG you need to set final image format to PNG because JPEG does not handle transparency.

```
$img->setImageFormat('png');
```